# terminating a process within itself in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Let's say I do this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    #Do something

x = Process(target = a)
x.start()
```

I want to use `x.terminate()` within the defined function but to do that I would need to add x as an argument, WHILE defining x and that isn't possible.

So my question is, how do I terminate the process within the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `return` from `a`, and the process will end. (Implicitly returning by running off the end of the function counts too.)

You'll need an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard for safe process creation, though:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Process(target=a)
    x.start()
```

Comment: So if I did `x.isalive()`, it would say it isn't?

Comment: @Krishi: After `a` returns, yes.

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that the code which is after the defined functions is running multiple times. What I mean is,in my actual program I am creating 4 processes. Despite having a return at the end of every defined function, the code after it is running 4 times at once.

Comment: @Krishi: [Entirely unrelated issue.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)

Comment: I'll try and understand that.